# log(conv) vs conv(log)

Tags: filters, convolution, spectrogram, cwt

Suppose an arbitrary, strictly positive $x[n]$, transformed as

$$
x_l[n] = \log(1 + C x[n]) \tag{0}
$$
where $C$ is freely chosen. Given the following, where $h[n]$ is a Gaussian lowpass filter (or any other strictly positive lowpass):
$$
\begin{align}
y_0 &= h[n] \star x_l[n] \tag{1} \\
y_1 &= \log(h[n] \star x[n]) \tag{2} \\
y_\text{ref} &= h[n] \star x[n] \tag {3}
\end{align}
$$

which one (between $(1)$ and $(2)$) is better in terms of:

- A) bringing extreme values closer together
- B) preserving characteristics of $y_\text{ref}$ (i.e. untransformed), such as time-domain of frequency-domain shape
- C) robustness/stability

The exact context is scattering transform - put simply, scalogram / spectrogram (modulus) convolved with Gaussian. I wonder whether it's preferred to take log *before* or *after* convolution. My results suggest latter $(1)$ is better for A, $(2)$ is better for B (see below), but I wonder whether the distinction has been studied in detail.

#### Example

[image]

[image]

"log" is as in $(0)$, and right shows the slice highlighted in left.

I find $(2)$'s edge over $(1)$ at A surprising, as I figured without log the small values would get "drowned out" in averaging (convolution with Gaussian along rows), and taking log after would do poorer at "recovery" than *first* taking log and then convolving. Results persist if I add noise or a second exponential chirp parallel in frequency.

Answer (score -1):

Regarding C), I'd say $y_0$ is better. Unless you put special constraints on the lowpass filter, the output of a positive input is by no means guaranteed to be positive as well. So even if $x$ is positive $h*x$ can easily have negative samples which after taking the log would result in a complex values.